# How to compute taylor series of $\sin{x}$ about $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to compute taylor series of $\sin{x}$ about  $a=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

We know $\sin{x}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Let $t=x-\frac{\pi}{4}$, then $t+\frac{\pi}{4}=x$

Then $\sin{(t+\frac{\pi}{4})}=\sin{(t+\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4})}=\cos{(t-\frac{\pi}{4})}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n(t-\frac{\pi}{4})^{2n}}{(2n)!}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^{2n}}{(2n)!}$.

Which part did I do wrong? Could someone provide a standard way to do such substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that
$f(a+x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{f^{(n)}(a)x^n}{n!}
$.

Putting
$f(x) = \sin(x)$
and
$a = \dfrac{\pi}{4}
$,
we get
$\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^{(n)}(\pi/4)x^n}{n!}
$.

The derivatives of $\sin$ cycle:
$\sin, \cos, -\sin, -\cos
$.
So the values of
$\sin^{(n)}(\pi/4)$
cycle as
$(\sqrt{2}/2)(1, 1, -1, -1)
$.
Using this,
I get

$\begin{array}\\
\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin^{(n)}(\pi/4)x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^3 \left(\dfrac{\sin^{(4n+k)}(\pi/4)x^{4n+k}}{(4n+k)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left(\dfrac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}+\dfrac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)!}-\dfrac{x^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!}-\dfrac{x^{4n+3}}{(4n+3)!}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \dfrac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}\left(1+\dfrac{x}{(4n+1)}-\dfrac{x^{2}}{(4n+1)(4n+2)}-\dfrac{x^{3}}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$